# jQuery nextUntil

Tags: jquery

OK I have some HTML like this:

```
<form>
<h3>
<table>
<h3>
<table>
<h3>
<table>
<h3>
<table>
<table>
<input name=action>
</form>
```

I began using `.next()` as there was only one element after each h3 but the last section has two tables.

I tried using:

```
jQuery(this).nextUntil('h3, input[name="action"]').detach();
```

This code basically creates tabs so each "this" is each h3 then the content is everything after the h3 till the enxt one.

I just need to figure out how to grab th last table as well.

Comment: In the worst case, you can add a hidden `h3` before `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would try the [next-siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/).

```
    $('h3 ~ table').each(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery(this).nextUntil('input[name="action"]', 'h3,table').detach();` i.e. according to http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Lee!

You should try using this:

```
$(this).nextUntil('input[name="action"]', 'h3,table').detach();
```

Note: change to `jQuery(this).nextUntil('input[name="action"]', 'h3,table').detach();` if you are using other JavaScript libraries.

Here is the link to the page in the jQuery documentation that describes `.nextUntil()`: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work for me it still didnt grab the last table.